# ST_DISTANCE isn't giving the expected result

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I don't get why `ST_DISTANCE` is giving me the same closest node when clearly it is not the one nearest to the starting point. Also, using 2 different starting points, I still have the same result.

My data is this one, I run in my pgadmin

```
SELECT id, ST_AsText (ST_Transform (the_geom, 4326)) FROM edges_noded order by id;
```

[image]

and I run this commands to get the closest node

```
SELECT id, 
       ST_Distance(the_geom,ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(124.263770, 8.265921),3857)) AS DIST, 
       ST_AsText (ST_Transform (the_geom, 4326)) 
FROM edges_noded 
LIMIT 1;

SELECT id, 
       ST_Distance(the_geom,ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(124.264505, 8.264620),3857)) AS DIST, 
       ST_AsText (ST_Transform (the_geom, 4326)) 
FROM edges_noded 
LIMIT 1;
```

these two commands give me the same nearest node.

Does `ST_DISTANCE` work for this kind of situations?

attached also is a visual of the situation.

[image: the small picture on the bottom left is the paths]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues that prevents getting the expected result.

First, you are using lat-long coordinates (4326) but declare them as 3857

```
ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(124.263770, 8.265921),4326)) AS DIST
```

Then the query computes the distance to the `geom` and return the 1st result. Since there is no ordering, a more or less random `geom` is used, regardless of its distance to the created point.

To get the nearest point, you would need to order by distance and keep the first result. It is a good habit to use the `<->` operator as it benefits from the spatial index (less important if only dealing with points though)

Computing distances in lat-long is meaningless as a degree of latitude has a different length - in meters - then a degree of longitude. It is also wrong to compute distances in 3857 as this projection introduces severe distortions. An alternative would be to compute the distance using the `geometry` datatype.

At last, if you have lots of points, you may want to restrict the distance ordering to nearby locations only.

```sql
WITH target as 
  (SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(124.263770, 8.265921),4326)::geography as the_geog)
SELECT e.id,
       ST_Distance(ST_Transform (e.the_geom, 4326)::geography, target.the_geog) AS dist,
       ST_AsText (ST_Transform (e.the_geom, 4326))
FROM edges_noded AS e, target
--Optionally restrict the ordering to nearby locations
--WHERE ST_DWithin(e.the_geom::geography, target.the_geog, 10000)
ORDER BY ST_Transform (e.the_geom, 4326)::geography <-> target.the_geog
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I've tried running your code and it shows "Only lon/lat coordinate systems are supported in geography.".
and I'm gonna try looking for the wrong part as i wait and hope that maybe you know what's wrong. But thanks anyway

Comment: @AbdulMalikMustapha ah yes, it was missing a reprojection. See the updated answer